# How to embed videos in Discord

Tags: discord, facebook-opengraph, embedded-video

I'm working on a clips system that serves short video files. I'm trying to have these video's embedded inside Discord so people can just send the link inside a Discord chat and you can watch the video in an embedded video player.

As far as I gathered, this should be possible by using OpenGraph and serving an MP4 video (unless I need my own video player?)

I am currently providing the following OpenGraph tags, and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong:

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Outplays">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://outplays.eu/Q5THkfY3">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
<meta property="og:title" content="Mini rengar xD">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://outplays.eu/Q5THkfY3/thumbnail.png">
<meta property="og:video" content="https://outplays.eu/Q5THkfY3/video">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://outplays.eu/Q5THkfY3/video">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="720">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1280">
```

(this is for the following clip: https://outplays.eu/Q5THkfY3)

But once sent in Discord, it comes out like this, without an inline video player:

[image: 1]

At the same time I just found out through Sentry that when I send this link in Discord, I get an `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` exception thrown.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and googling about it but I can't really seem to find why it doesn't work.

Comment: To embed a video, **you have to share the video in mp4, WebM, or MOV formats**. 

[Source 1](https://www.remote.tools/remote-work/how-to-send-videos-on-discord#:~:text=Discord%20supports%20sharing%20of%20any,desktop%20only%2C%20not%20on%20mobile.)
[Source 2](https://invideo.io/blog/how-to-send-videos-on-discord/)

Comment: @clxrity sure but that's not exactly what I'm trying to do, I have the video hosted on my website and I'm wondering how to have that embedded when a link from my site is pasted into Discord. Similar to how sites like YouTube and Reddit do it, though I can't exactly spot my mistake.

Comment: Try making your `og:video` metadata property point to a file such as `.MP4`?

Comment: @clxrity ok wauw that did the trick, I could've sworn I tried that before but apparently not. Thank you very much! ^^